# Is there a way to create multiple reports (one for each sample say) in a Snakemake worklow

Tags: snakemake

I'm developing a snakemake pipeline to QC a large set of data. I'd like to generate a set of plots for each dataset and then generate a html report that combines the plots with some text. Looking at https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/reporting.html, this will only generate one report for the whole pipeline. Is there a way to do this per dataset?

The functionality to do this is still available via the old way of generating reports with `report()`, but this is now deprecated. Wondering if there is a recommended way to achieve something like the below with the newer report functionality.

```
from snakemake.utils import report
rule createreport:
    input:
        plot1 = "results/{dataset}/plot1.pdf",
    output:
        report = "reports/{dataset}.html"
    run:
        report("""
        This plot shows etc...
        plot1_

        """, output.report, **input)
```